# Property 'to' does not exist on type 'FunctionMatchers<any>'

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I am using React, Jest and Typescript and following [these](https://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/props.html) docs to create a unit test using this code:

`expect(HorizontalNotIndented.props().includedProp).to.equal(dummyValue);`

I have all types installed but I am getting the error `Property 'to' does not exist on type 'FunctionMatchers<any>'.` when I use `to` in the test.

It seems there maybe some confusion over whether `to` is coming form Jest or Jasmine? I'm not 100% sure but I am following the Enzyme docs exactly.

#### Update

I am now having problems structuring this test - following the docs and the comment below does not seem to allow the test to work. I am trying to test for props rendering properly:

```
const dummyValue = {
  background: {
    color: 'rgba(38, 176, 17, 0.2)',
    value: 100,
  },
  foreground: {
    color: 'rgb(38, 176, 17)',
    value: 80,
  },
};

const HorizontalNotIndented = shallow(
  <Horizontal
    value={dummyValue}
  />,
);

HorizontalNotIndented.setProps({
  value
});

describe('HCGauge', () => {
  test('Test to see if props are in rendered component', () => {
expect(HorizontalNotIndented.props().value).toEqual(dummyValue);
```

Throws the error:

```sh
    expect(received).toEqual(expected) // deep equality

    Expected: {"background": {"color": "rgba(38, 176, 17, 0.2)", "value": 100}, "foreground": {"color": "rgb(38, 176, 17)", "value": 80}}
    Received: undefined

      62 |   test('Test to see if props are in rendered component', () => {
      63 |     // expect('value' in HorizontalNotIndented.props()).toEqual(dummyValue);
    > 64 |     expect(HorizontalNotIndented.props().includedProp).toEqual(dummyValue);
         |
```

Comment: I fixed this by uninstalling `@types/jasmine`

Comment: Is my problem in Update 2 related to the fact that `value` is required as prop by typescript and so 'setting' it as a prop using `.setProps` is making the test fail?

Comment: I have a TypeScript AWS service with an Angular frontend. After I put the Angular frontend in the repo with the AWS service, I started seeing "Property 'toHaveLength' does not exist on type 'FunctionMatchers<any>'". Your fix of uninstalling `@types/jasmine` worked for me. :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Jest you should use `.toBe()` instead of `.to.equal()` as described here:

https://jestjs.io/docs/en/expect.html#tobevalue

If the parameter (`dummyValue`) is an object you should use `.toMatchObject()` as described here:

https://jestjs.io/docs/en/expect.html#tomatchobjectobject

Comment: Thanks for your answer - using your examples and the Enzyme docs I cannot get the test to run properly - have updated the question

Answer (score 0):

I was facing similar issue while using [jest-image-matcher](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jest-image-matcher) in TypeScript

```
Property 'toMatchImage' does not exist on type 'JestMatchers<any>'.
```

***Solution:***

Jest Allows us to add customise matcher, in order to let jest know about this custom matcher we need to extend matcher type

```js
// filename: index.d.ts
export {};
declare global {
  namespace jest {
    interface Matchers < R > {
      toMatchImage(image: Buffer, options ? : {}): R;
    }
  }
}
```

Similarly we can add/replace new custom matcher as per requirements.